# jQuery does not call struts2 action?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2

I have followed the autocomplete [example](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=243), but things not working out.

the JSP search page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
       <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.ajaxQueue.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/thickbox-compressed.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <s:textfield id="listCats" name="displayedCatId" key="label_choose_topic" size="80" cssClass="selectedCat" />
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $().ready(function() {
            $("#listCats").autocomplete('/listCategory.action', {
              minChars: 1,
                max: 15,
              multiple: false,
              autoFill: true
            });
       });
</script>
```

in struts.xml

```
<action name="listCategory" class="qaplus.action.question.LoadCategoryAction" method="loadCategory">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/list_category.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The problem is that jQuery function does not call the **listCateory** action.

Am I missing something?

Edit:
The java script console reports:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined jquery.autocomplete.js:83
$.Autocompleter jquery.autocomplete.js:83
(anonymous function) jquery.autocomplete.js:32
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.9.0.js:631
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.9.0.js:253
$.fn.extend.autocomplete jquery.autocomplete.js:31
(anonymous function) sample.jsp:34
fire jquery-1.9.0.js:1017
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.0.js:1127
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.0.js:416
DOMContentLoaded
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the firebug console?

Comment: as your remind, I notice the console produces images/loadingAnimation.gif 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you show the order in which you have included the jquery.js and autocomplete.js because it seems like the autocomplete plugin is not loaded, as far as the image 404 is concerned that is not an issue...

Comment: you meant the ones included in the jsp file? Aren't they already there?

Comment: my bad i havent seen the question, apparantly you have included the js files in the correct order, make sure the autocomplete plugin doesnt conflict with anyother plugin

Comment: alo instead of `$().ready(function() {` it should be like `$(document).ready(function() {` or the short hand `$(function(){//your code});` because the way you have done it is not recomended http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

The name of the action in jQuery autocomplete does not match the action defined in struts.xml

Please change autocomplete('/listCateory.action') to autocomplete('/listCategory.action')

Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: they do match, cause' it just the mistyping when I posted the question on SO. In code, they are matched. BTW, I have updated the question with errors from the javascript console

Answer (score 0):

You autocomplete plugin is relying on the jQuery.browser object, which is depcreated since jQuery 1.3 and has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

So you either have to update your autocomplete plugin or use jQuery 1.8.